# Race Condition Warning OpenTSDB

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper, opentsdb

I am getting a race condition warning while running multiple imports simultaneously to openTSDB. Following is one of the log sequences showing the race condition.

> 2013-08-21 14:34:24,745 INFO  [main] UniqueId: Creating an ID for
>   kind='tagv' name='25447'
>
> 2013-08-21 14:34:24,747 INFO  [main] UniqueId: Got ID=307 for
>   kind='tagv' name='25447'
>
> 2013-08-21 14:34:24,752 WARN  [main] UniqueId: Race condition: tried
>   to assign ID 307 to tagv:25447, but CAS failed on
>   PutRequest(table="tsdb-uid", key="25447", family="id",
>   qualifiers=["tagv"], values=["\x00\x013"],
>   timestamp=9223372036854775807, lockid=-1, durable=true,
>   bufferable=true, attempt=0, region=null), which indicates this UID
>   must have been allocated concurrently by another TSD. So ID 307 was
>   leaked.

Following questions I have:

1. Since it is a warning, is it that the record is actually written and not skipped?
2. At the end it says, 'ID 307 was leaked', so is some other ID assigned to the record?
3. How to verify that the said record has been written in HBase's table named 'tsdb-uid'? (HBase shell commands, I tried a few but in vain).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This just means that a UID was allocated for nothing, but otherwise everything is fine.  If you are worried about the state of your `tsdb-uid` table, you could run the `tsdb uid fsck` command, and it will probably report that some UIDs are allocated but unused.

If you see the message only occasionally, you can ignore it.  If you see it a lot, then the only undesirable consequence is that you're burning through the UID space faster than you should be, so you may run out of UIDs sooner (there are 16777215 possible UIDs for each of: metric names, tag names, tag values).

Comment: Thanks man. That's a bit of relief. Do we have any solution for this? Some config or something? As for us there are around 25% of such entries going into Race conditions. Also when you say that 16777215 possible UIDs are available, is it for per metric per tag or is it for total value?

Comment: All in all, can have 16777215 metrics, 16777215 tag names, 16777215 tag values.  We're looking at ways to reduce the number of times this happens while still keeping the optimization that we put in place in the first place that led to this.

Comment: Good to hear that, please let me know if you find a solution. Thanks again.